# Tracking user views in a news feed app on Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

I am currently building a news feed app and am trying to implement a tracking feature where i can check if the user has looked over the post. Currently i was thinking of implementing tracking by calling a service when a when a user interacts with the post by commenting or upvoting. **Is there a better method to track posts on the user viewing it?**

I couldn't find any methods or lifecycle hooks that could address this on angular docs.

Comment: This does not have any connections with Angular life-cycle hooks. Service will do fine. If you want to create something meaningful you will want to connect that service with some server side code. For example when user likes or comments the post, you will send that information to the server. In the response you can return number of likes or comments for that particular post and then update the UI.

Comment: thanks for the response, well that's my current implementation. However how could i track a post that has been viewed and not interacted with. Consider a scenario where i read the post, don't like or comment on it and scroll to next post. Any suggestion on how to track this post.

Comment: have you thought of using the analytics for the same, you can use any analytics tool which would do the job just fine?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, was looking for some methods in angular to try to make it work. Alas, i have haven't found any.